# Trying to Remove Stubborn Admin Bar (for ALL users, incl admin) from Avada Wordpress Site

Tags: php, wordpress

We have tried adding many variations of the "show_admin_bar(false);" to our functions.php file to remove the admin bar on our Wordpress site to no avail. Have tried clearing caches both in my server, my site, and in the browser multiple times (after each instance). I checked the forums and tried some of the solutions here, but most are to remove the bar for all **but** admins (I don't want it at all on the front end) and the rest I've tried haven't worked.

We've even tried just removing it in the dashboard > users area, though I know that would only apply to a specific user (and it still shows, even though I've checked for it to be off on my account).

Unfortunately, I didn't keep track of all the variations of the "show_admin_bar(false);" command I tried as I thought I'd be able to get this to work since it wasn't a problem in the past, but I do know this one doesn't work: add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

We also want to make sure whatever the solution is, it removes the gap where the admin bar once was, since I remember that being a problem in the past with the Avada theme we're using.

**Site Info**

Theme: Avada v 5.2.2

WordPress v 4.8.1

Website: https://www.outdoorwomensalliance.com

Any other info needed from me to help figure out why this bar won't leave me in peace?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you've deactivated the theme (while the admin bar is disabled for your user) to confirm that its been added by it? If it's not the theme itself, have you tried disabling all plugins, to see if any of them are causing it to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set filter priority, here is the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/) for filter

Example code.

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false', 99);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look, Aliraza! It seems to have worked! But it also presented another challenge: in the photo grid at the bottom (which corresponds with posts on our site) one of the photos is now missing and instead shows the Alt tag for the photo. I cleared the browser cache in both Chrome and Safari and both are showing an empty space where a photo once was. It doesn't look like I can add a screenshot, so if you go to https://www.outdoorwomensalliance.com on the homepage and scroll to the grid of photos (should be 6 total) you'll notice a gap there. Ideas?

Comment: https://www.outdoorwomensalliance.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Force-of-Nature-Urban-700x441.jpg image exists on this url